# Using extJS GUI only

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I am building a web application using a PHP MVC framework and jQuery, but I would like to use extJS layouts as the GUI of the Application. The whole core of the App is built using the framework and jQuery, I just want to use ExtJS to create the Layout. It will consist of a two column style with a left menu and tabbed navigation; it is the only I want to use from ExtJS.

The question is: Is it worth it? (taking into account the license restrictions and the large ExtJS is). Are there some alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't do it. Developing with Ext requires quiet some time and is mostly worth it when you use the functioanlity offered by the Ext framework. From yourquestion I understand that you use jQuery for the functionalities of the application and Ext only for the layout. That doesn't seem worth the time and work for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the same, but the client demanded the App to be 'extjs-like' and there was no time for designing :( I already managed to have the extjs-layout working and I am on the App itself now